# How to convert struct to NULL if value is default

Tags: c#, .net

How to convert struct to nullable struct if the value is default value. In the code below the `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals` return false when variable of type `int` has zero value

```
    public static Nullable<T> ConvertToNullIfDefault<T>(this T src) where T : struct
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(src))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return (Nullable<T>)src;
    }
```

Test

```
    [Fact]
    public void ConvertToNullIfDefault_ReturnsNull_WhenIntegerIsDefault()
    {
        var val = default(int);

        var result = val.ConvertToNullIfDefault();

        Assert.Null(result);
    }
```

Comment: Aren't you comparing the default equality comparer for `T` to `src`, rather than comparing `default(T)` to `src`?

Comment: `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(src)` - this does not do what you think it does

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is to use the `IEquatable<T>` constraint:

```
    public static Nullable<T> ConvertToNullIfDefault<T>(this T src)
        where T : struct, IEquatable<T>
    {
        if( src.Equals( default(T) ) )
        {
            return null;
        }

        return (Nullable<T>)src;
    }
```